# Tensorboard does not show accuracy graph for Custom Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorboard

I have been training a custom Object Detector using the Tensorflow Object Detection API (Network: SSD Mobilenet V1). There are screenshots of Tensorboard with the accuracy of the network being shown, however, I have a bunch of metrics being displayed except for accuracy. Are there any specific steps that need to be taken to display the accuracy using tensorboard?

I am using the updated model_main.py and the following python command;

```
python model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config  \
    --model_dir=training \
    --num_train_steps=560000 \
    --num_eval_steps=3 \
    --alsologtostderr
```

Answer (score 0):

How long have you been training it for?
It will run for a number of steps before the doing the first evaluation. Precision and recall data should show up when you wait a bit longer

Answer (score 0):

to display precision and recall in Tensorboard you should run this command after training your model so that the training folder will contain the checkpoints of your trained model

```
python model_main_tf2.py \ 
    --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config  \
    --model_dir=training \
    --checkpoint_dir= training
```

this command will generate a folder named eval inside the training folder
and to display result you should add the path to your eval folder (training/eval) in tensorboard
!!! this command for TensorFlow 2 object detection API